# How to write Ajax call delete method with specific id in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do I write this peace of Ajax call that is written in jQuery, completely in vanilla JavaScript

What should be converted into vanilla javascript

```js
$.ajax({
 type: "DELETE",
url: "/users/delete/" + $(".deleteUser").data('id');
}}
```

What I think it should be, but the console log gave me the following error message : request is not defined. And I am afraid it would not pick up the id.

```js
request.open("DELETE", "/users/delete/" + this.dataSet('id'));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get any more vanilla then good old xmlhttprequest.

```
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open('DELETE', "http://127.0.0.1:80/users/delete/", true);
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {

        dostuff = this.responseText;
  };//end onreadystate
 xhr1.send();
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Missed by 40 seconds :p

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the new fetch API:

```
fetch(url, { method: 'DELETE' })
    .then((res)=>{
        res.json()
        window.location.href = '/'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`request` is node module, it is not available in browser (altho there is a fork for browser, still it is not vanilla JS, but a library instead).

If you are fine with not supporting IE (just IE, edge should be fine), you can use `fetch` API:

```
fetch("/users/delete/" + $(".deleteUser").data('id'), {
    method: "DELETE",
}}.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Btw I guess you also want to get rid of the `$.data` call, this is vanilla JS version:

```
var id = document.querySelector('.deleteUser').getAttribute('data-id');
```